# Resize image in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Can anyone help me how to implement resizing image in Laravel?

I have this code only:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $destination = base_path() . '/public/images/ServiceImages';
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;

        if(!empty($data['Image'])){
            unlink($destination.$data['Image']);
        }

        $file->move($destination, $fileName);
        $service->image=$fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Laravel does not have a default resize of image. But most Laravel developers use '**Image intervention**' in handling the image. It is easy to use.

To install (Image intervention):

**STEP 1** Run

```
composer require intervention/image
```

**STEP 2** On your config/app.php:

In the $providers array, add the following:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

In the $aliases array,add the following:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

If you have problems your GD library is missing, install it

- PHP5: sudo apt-get install php5-gd
- PHP7: sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

To use on your controller.

**STEP 3**

On top of your controller

`use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;`

**STEP 4**

On your method (there are several ways but this will give you an idea)

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {

    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
    $image_resize->save(public_path('images/ServiceImages/' .$filename));

}
```

Reference [here](http://image.intervention.io/).

Comment: You get my +1 for this. Thanks.

Comment: A limitation on this library is - it can't save the uploaded image in a new directory.

Comment: does resizing images decrease their size ?

Comment: @Sanaulla the main disadvantage of this package loses the DPI (Dots per inch) of the image

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya yes its decreases the size also

Comment: If you use `use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;` anyway then you don't need to do Step 1&2.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post but I consider posting a solution which is independent of installing any package.

```
$image = $request->file('image');

$image_name = rand(111111, 888999)*time() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$thumb_name = rand(111111, 888999)*time() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');

$image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
$orgImgPath = $destinationPath. '/'.$image_name;
$thumbPath = $destinationPath. '/'.$thumb_name;
shell_exec("convert $orgImgPath -resize 200x200\! $thumbPath");
```

This will forcely resize your image to 200x200 because of the ! but if you like to keep the aspect ratio then ! need to be removed. This code will save the original uploaded and thumbnail will be generated.

Comment: but it requires your access to the command line, which many hosting provider do not allow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) for this task.

Simply install it with composer

```
composer require intervention/image
```

and just use it like this:

```
\Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::make('public/foo')->fit(100)->save($path);
```

---

**Remarks**

- **Service Provider**
  The intervention image provides a Service Provider for Laravel. You may add the service provider manually as explained [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation). After that, you may push the configuration file to Laravel. However, the configuration has only one option and that is the image driver. `gd` is default , so if you don't want to change it, there is no need to use the service provider and configuration.
- **Alias** Instead of the service Provider, you could create an alias in `config/app`:

  ```
  'Image' => Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::class
  ```

  Then you can use it like this:

  ```
  \Image::make('public/foo')->fit(100)->save($path);
  ```
- **Testing** You can still Laravel's [file upload tests](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads) when using intervention image. For details, see [How to fake image upload for testing with Intervention image package using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592101/how-to-fake-image-upload-for-testing-with-intervention-image-package-using-larav/62075597#62075597)