# How to resize the image in array in laravel framwork?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

```
$allImageNames = [];

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $files = $request->file('image');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $imageName = microtime() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('images');
        $file->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
        $allImageNames[] = $imageName; 
    }

    $allImageNames = json_encode($allImageNames);
    $data['images'] = $allImageNames;   
}
```

i have done this to upload the bigger image but how do i resize the image size

Comment: What have you tried? A simple search query ("php resize image") in your favorite search engine will turn up thousands of clear tutorials and useful packages.

Comment: For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2