# Image resize Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, resize, image-resizing

I have a question about to resize an image in Laravel with intervention.io (Link: http://image.intervention.io/

My question is that I don't understand how to input in my code, can somebody help me with showing the example? Thank you in advance!

MY CODE:

**account.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Account
@endsection

@section('content')
    <section class="row new-post">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <header><h3>Your Account</h3></header>
            <form action="{{ route('account.save') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->first_name }}" id="first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Image (only .jpg)</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Account</button>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>


    @if (Storage::disk('local')->has($user->first_name . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg'))
        <section class="row new-post">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src="{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => $user->first_name . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg']) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </section>

    @endif
@endsection
```

**User.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change width or height also ?  and did you install intervention yet or not?

Comment: Welcome, have you read http://image.intervention.io/use/basics ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Hi @gaurav Gupta,

Yes I want to change the width and heigth, i didn't install intervention yet, how can i do that with Laravel?

Hope to hear soon.

Comment: Hi @kerbholz, 
Yes, it doesn't work for me out.

Comment: Hi @SamarthSaxena,
yes, doesn't work

Comment: you can install it with help of composer also keep in mind don't install latest version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2 There is steps as well on first answer just follow that

Comment: Hi @GauravGupta, 
Thanks, i just did that, what to do next?

Comment: Route::get('resize/{profile}/{id}/{width}/{height}', function(  $profile, $id, $width,$height)
{
  $img = Image::make('file path/'.$profile.'/'.$id);
 // $img = Image::make(public_path().'/'.$profile.'/'.$id);
  $img->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
  $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
return $img->response($img);
});

Comment: @Jennifer does it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize image in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 0):

Have you written necessary functions in controller for handling your image files ?
If answer is  yes, then you just install the Intervention Image package on your laravel project and add the code for image resizing in that controller functions. After uploading logic just add [necessary lines to resize image](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize)  in your controller function .
It's something like this

```
public function resizeImagePost(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);


    $image = $request->file('image');
    $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();


    $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $img->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);


    $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);


    $this->postImage->add($input);


    return back()
        ->with('success','Image Upload successful')
        ->with('imageName',$input['imagename']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the intervention installation using composer (Auto detect version)

```
composer require intervention/image
```

And about resizing image

```
$image = $manager->make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
```

Example : This is in my controller method

```
/* TOP OF THE FILE */
use Request;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

public someFunctionname(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
      $extension = '';
      $files = $request->file('image');

      $mime = Image::make($files->getRealPath())->mime();
      if ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {
          $extension = '.jpg';
      } elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {
          $extension = '.png';
      } elseif ($mime == 'image/jpg') {
          $extension = '.jpg';
      } else {
          $extension = '';
      }

      $originalName = pathinfo($files->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $filename = time() . '_' . $originalName . $extension;
      $storagePath = public_path('uploads/profileImages/');

      if (!File::exists($storagePath)) File::makeDirectory($storagePath, 775);
      Image::make($files->getRealPath())->save($storagePath . '/' . $filename, 100)->resize(500, 500);

      $savePathInDB = asset('uploads/profileImages/' . $filename);

    } else {

      $savePathInDB = asset('uploads/demoImages/demoImage.jpg');

    }
}
```

Hope That Works. Happy Coding