# In controller its saving the image and how can i resize it to 150,150

Tags: laravel, resize

its working but how to resize image in it

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $image = Input::file('image');

    if (isset($image)) {
        $directory = public_path() . '/uploads/programs';
        $medium_size = public_path() . '/uploads/programs/100X100/';
        $thumb_nails = public_path() . '/uploads/programs/100X100/';
        if (!file_exists($directory)) File::makeDirectory($directory, 0777, true, true);
        $filename = sha1(time() . time()) . ".png";
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = str_random(40) . "$filename";
        $upload_success = $image->move($directory, $filename);
        $input['image'] = $filename;
    }

    product::create($input);

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2)