# Problem with resizing images after uploading to laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good evening, I would like to add the resize function of the images when an image is uploaded on my site, I have installed the necessary dependencies and I have included in the config/app files the provider and the aliases. But I find this error:
`production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::resize does not exist.` 
I put the part of the code below:

```
    public function imageProfile(Request $request)  
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rules = array(
            'profile-image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:8192|dimensions:min_width=160,min_height=160',
        );

        $customMessages = [
            'profile-image.required' => 'E\' richiesta una immagine per cambiare immagine di profilo.',
            'profile-image.image' => 'Devi inserire un immagine valida.',
            'profile-image.mimes' => 'L\'immagine inserita non ha un formato adatto.',
            'profile-image.dimensions' => 'L\'immagine deve essere minimo 160x160.',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $customMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $this->validationErrorsToString($validator->errors())]);
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('profile-image')) {
            $number = mt_rand(1,1000000);
            $image = $request->file('profile-image');
            $name = $user->username.'-'.Carbon::now()->toDateString().'-'.$number.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = 'uploads/profile';
            $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
            $image->resize(200,200);

            $user->image_profile = $imagePath;
            $user->save();
            $html =  $imagePath;

            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html, 'image' => $imagePath]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help me, and have a good day

Comment: are you using intervention image package ?

Comment: there is no resize function available in the file upload object.

Comment: yes exactly @ kmg kumar. So he need to use image intervention

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2
may this link help you

Answer (score 7):

Laravel does not have a default resize of image. But most laravel developers use 'Image intervention' in handling the image. (Easy to use)

To install (Image intervention):

STEP 1 Run

```
composer require intervention/image
```

STEP 2 On your config/app.php:

In the $providers array, add the following:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

In the $aliases array,add the following:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

If you have problems your GD librabry is missing, intall it

```
PHP5: sudo apt-get install php5-gd
PHP7: sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

~~ To use on your controller ~~

STEP 3 On top of your controller

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

STEP 4 On your method (there are several ways but this will give you an idea)

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {

$image       = $request->file('image');
$filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

$image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
$image_resize->resize(300, 300);
$image_resize->save(public_path('images/ServiceImages/' .$filename));

}
```