# Generate Thumbnail of Uploaded video in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I am trying to create a thumbnail of the uploaded image in Laravel.

but there is no particular doc for this. It's possible without the FFmpeg.

I didn't want to use FFmpeg. please anyone can help on this.

Comment: use intervention image library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358510/resize-image-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Why do you not want to use the ffmpeg?

Comment: FFmpeg is the best way to do it. Besides, there are not many options.

Answer (score -2):

For make an thumbnail out of image you can apply intervention package,
i tried

https://github.com/Intervention/image

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31367213)